# WHERE (set of conditions) OR (set of second conditions) OR ... written elegantly

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, vba

I have the following problem:

I have a Oracle-database with Material Properties in it and I am developing a front-end in Excel-VBA for it.

There is a view ALL_TESTS which represents the whole table from which I want to load all properties in a Datasheet. To be precise I got a list of PROPERTIES, measured each with a specific TEST under specific CONDITIONS with a STATE of the specimen. For one MATERIAL of a COMPANY i always want the whole package to be loaded.

if I would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TESTS WHERE COMPANY in (Company1, Company2, ...)
                        AND MATERIAL (Material1,Material2, ... )
                        AND Test in (Test1,Test2, ...)
                        AND Property in (Property1, Property2, ...)
                        AND Condition in (Condition1, Condition2, ...)
                        AND State in (State1,State2, ...)
```

I will get not only the tests I want but also records where the indexes do not match eachother. For example when the record matches company1, material2, test3,property4 and State2. But this is not what I want, I want the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TESTS WHERE (COMPANY = Company1
                        AND MATERIAL = Material1
                        AND Test = Test1
                        AND Property = Property1
                        AND Condition = Condition1
                        AND State = State1)

                        OR (COMPANY = Company2
                        AND MATERIAL = Material2
                        AND Test = Test2
                        AND Property = Property2
                        AND Condition = Condition2
                        AND State = State2)
                        OR ...
```

I there a way I can write that in a more elegant way, then just constructing a SQL query which is super long?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TESTS
WHERE (COMPANY, MATERIAL, Test, Property, Condition, State) IN
          ( (Company1, Material1, Test1, Property1, Condition1, State1),
            (Company2, Material2, Test2, Property2, Condition2, State2)
          )
```

Comment: I choose your solution and implemented it. Could it be, that this would not work if some of the conditions are NULL?

Comment: Indeed not going to work with some properties being null - Then again, the same goes for the where clause described in the initial question.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda . . . Rik is exactly correct.  This behaves the same way as the equals in your question.

Comment: I correct myself: I am 90% sure that there are no NULL values, there are only empty values. You can imagine that for example a tensile test has parameters like tensile speed, temperature and testing orientation of the material. But a simple measurement of the density has no such parameters. This means that the testing conditions sometimes have values and sometimes do not have values (empty). But they are not NULL (unknown).

Answer (score 0):

If you had the data for the matching companies in another table, then you could do a simple join and obtain your result:

```
SELECT at.*
FROM ALL_TESTS
INNER JOIN MATCHING_COMPANIES mc
    ON at.COMPANY   = mc.COMPANY AND
       at.MATERIAL  = mc.MATERIAL AND
       at.Test      = mc.Test AND
       at.Property  = mc.Property AND
       at.Condition = mc.Condition AND
       at.State     = mc.State
```

Of course, this requires a separate table, but creating a temp table in Oracle or VBA hopefully is not so much trouble than it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

Put your where in a (temp) table (columns: MATERIAL, Test, Property, Condition, State), insert the possible values into it (every OR is a row), then inner join this table to the original (ALL_TESTS), with all the columns from the temp table like:

```
Select *
from ALL_TESTS
inner join temp1 on ALL_TESTS.MATERIAL = temp1.MATERIAL 
AND ALL_TESTS.Test = temp1.Test
AND ALL_TESTS.Property = temp1.Property
.... all other columns
```

And so you could have a lot of rows in the temp1, all a different OR, and a simple select to ask for it

Comment: Seems to be a good solution, however I do not want to write from this sheet into the database. It should only be a display vehicle, I have the idea to make it a read only tool for users. In this way I can be sure that a user or a bug cannot manipulate data on the database. I will try the first answer, although I think your answer would be better performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gordon's solution I can suggest to use oracle object types with custom compare logic to handle NULL comparison issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_obj as object(
  company varchar2(100),
  material varchar2(100),
  property varchar2(100),
  condition varchar2(100),
  map member function get_unique_key return varchar2  
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY test_obj as 
  map member function get_unique_key return varchar2
  as
  begin
    return nvl(company,'?')||'|'||nvl(material,'?')||'|'||nvl(property,'?')||'|'||nvl(condition,'?');
  end;  
end;
/

DROP TABLE all_tests;

CREATE TABLE all_tests
(
  test          VARCHAR2(100),
  test_obj      TEST_OBJ
)
;

insert into all_tests
select 'TEST1', test_obj('XXX', null, 'test', null)
  from dual 
;

select * from all_tests
where test_obj = test_obj('XXX', null, 'test', null);
```

> ```
> TEST     TEST_OBJ
> ------   --------------
> TEST1    (XXX, , test, )
> ```